# Verify Slack JSON? Not getting line breaks

Tags: botframework

Is there a way to see the raw output of your bot to different chat agents?  My \n line breaks aren't carrying through all the way to slack. I don't know if it's a slack bug or a framework bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent a paragraph break you need to have a blank line.

Markdown like this:

```
This is
paragraph one

This is 
paragraph two
```

Will be rendered as

```
This is paragraph one
This is paragraph two
```

See: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/